# What is のを doing here?

Tags: grammar, particle-を, parsing

> ⁠　歌島丸は那覇{なは}に着いた。税関の検疫をうけ、入港し、荷揚げをした。船は二三日の碇泊を強いられた。内地へもってかえる鉄屑{スクラップ}を、運天{うんてん}から積み込む**のを**、不開港である運天へまわってよいという許可が、なかなか下りなかったからである。運天は沖縄島の北部にあって、戦時中米軍が最初に上陸した地点である。

What is this のを doing after「運天から積み込む」? 「まわる」is intransitive.

Let me add a similar example from the same book. It's 潮騒 by 三島由紀夫. The quotes are from chapters 14 and 12.

> 一昔前までこの島の子が母を斥{さ}してエヤと呼んでいたのは、王子が「部屋」と妻を呼んだ**のを**、幼ない御子{みこ}がエヤと訛{なま}って呼びはじめたのに起るという。

Comment: I would say it's poorly written, including punctuation.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how are you reading this book? Kindle? Physical book?

Comment: It's a physical book. I had it shipped from Japan through Amazon.

Comment: の is simply the 代名詞. 積み込むの = 積み込むこと(the action of loading). Depending on the context, though. 積み込むの could also be 積み込む者(someone who loads).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you are probably aware, it is nominalizing の + を.

A possibility is to consider there is omission after を. For example, 積み込むのを（行うときに）. But I guess it is a miswriting affected by 運天へまわって鉄屑を積み込むのを許可する.

[edit] Another (still vaguely wrong) possibility is that の=船(=歌島丸) and を means 対して, so that the phrase means *to the ship loading scraps from Unten...*

Comment: I remembered another similar quote from the same book, so I added it to the question.

Comment: @ignorantFid I think the second one is more regular. The basic structure is AをBと訛って呼ぶ.  の can be considered a simple nominalizer or 王子が「部屋」と妻を呼んだ**呼び方**.